# Pandas: datetime indexed series to time indexed date columns dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime indexed series like this:

```
2018-08-27 17:45:01  1
2018-08-27 16:01:12  1
2018-08-27 13:48:47  1
2018-08-26 22:26:40  2
2018-08-26 20:10:42  1
2018-08-26 18:20:32  1
2018-08-25 23:07:51  1
2018-08-25 01:46:08  1
2018-09-18 14:08:23  1
2018-09-17 19:38:38  1
2018-09-15 22:40:45  1
```

What is an elegant way to reformat this into a time indexed dataframe whose columns are dates? For example:

```
          2018-10-24  2018-06-28  2018-10-23
15:16:41         1.0         NaN         NaN
15:18:16         1.0         NaN         NaN
15:21:42         1.0         NaN         NaN
23:35:00         NaN         NaN         1.0
23:53:13         NaN         1.0         NaN
```

Current approach:

```
time_date_dict = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, int))
for i in series.iteritems():
  datetime = i[0]
  value = i[1]
  time_date_dict[datetime.time()][datetime.date()] = value
time_date_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(time_date_dict, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
df1 = pd.pivot(s.index.time, s.index.date, s)
#if want strings index and columns names
#df1 = pd.pivot(s.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), s.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), s)
print (df1)
date      2018-08-25  2018-08-26  2018-08-27  2018-09-15  2018-09-17  \
date                                                                   
01:46:08         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
13:48:47         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN   
14:08:23         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
16:01:12         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN   
17:45:01         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN   
18:20:32         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN   
19:38:38         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0   
20:10:42         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN   
22:26:40         NaN         2.0         NaN         NaN         NaN   
22:40:45         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN   
23:07:51         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   

date      2018-09-18  
date                  
01:46:08         NaN  
13:48:47         NaN  
14:08:23         1.0  
16:01:12         NaN  
17:45:01         NaN  
18:20:32         NaN  
19:38:38         NaN  
20:10:42         NaN  
22:26:40         NaN  
22:40:45         NaN  
23:07:51         NaN
```